# I am stuck while styling the line plot in in jupyter_notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, line-plot

Straight to the point: I wrote code for `lineplot` but when I tried to change its style to `"dark"`, I failed.

Here is the code that I tried, can someone make correction, please!

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
phool = sns.load_dataset("iris")
phool
sns.lineplot(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", data=phool)
plt.title("Flower's bed")

# style changing
sns.set_style("dark")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, just run the cell twice (*in the same kernel session*) because Jupyter will remember the seaborn style. Or even better, move back [`set_style`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html) before [`lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) :

```
sns.set_style("dark")

phool = sns.load_dataset("iris")

sns.lineplot(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", data=phool)
plt.title("Flower's bed")

plt.show();
```

You can also make it temporary styled-plot with [`axes_style`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.axes_style.html#seaborn.axes_style) :

```
with sns.axes_style("dark"):
    sns.lineplot(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", data=phool)
```

Output :

[image]